# after jquery validating, $.ajax return the html source code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem when validating a form, the fields are correctly checked, but it return the current html source code instead of the value inside "ctrl.php", in other words the stuff inside the "success bloc" is done but I get nothing from "ctrl.php", just the current page in html is returned:(

Any idea ?

```
$("#form_contest").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form){
        var email=$("#email").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ctrl.php",
            data:{name:$("#name").val(),email:email},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data); //data is the current source code??
                //other stuff after is okay
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

the html form :

```
<form id="form_contest" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />         
  <input type="submit" id="submit-contest" name="submit-contest" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

ctrl.php  :

```
<?php
echo 1;
?>
```

Comment: how exactly are u triggering the `validate()` ? are you clicking on `submit` button ?

Comment: yes, I simply click the button..

Comment: How about `e.preventDefault()` inside your submit handler?

Comment: Exactly i think ur form is getting posted so use e.preventDefault() in click button handler and then validate ur form and act on the validation result

Comment: I just solved the problem, the page ctrl.php couldn't be reached and I had an nginx rule that redirected 404 error to the homepage, thank you anyway for both

Comment: @Arkantos, that is not how the jQuery Validate plugin works.  The `.validate()` method does not get called on button click.  The `.validate()` method only gets called once on DOM ready and the `click` is then captured automatically.  Please review the docs.  Thanks.

Comment: I get it now.. validate() itself will register a form submit handler on our form. On submit, it will do all the validations and finally it will invoke submitHandler function where we can choose to do either an Ajax call or a simple form submit. Thanks Sparky :-)

Answer (score 0):

the page ctrl.php couldn't be reached and I had an nginx rule that redirected 404 error to the homepage. Not easy to find.. but that's why ajax always gave me the homepage source code..